# Is there a way to make a software generated CSS sheet more readable?

Tags: css

I'm currently working on editing my work's website, it needs just a few touch ups here and there to update it and neaten a few things up. Web work was never my strongest suit, but I can edit HTML and CSS usually with some level of competency.

The issue I'm having is the third party who originally developed the website looks to have used some kind of software to generate the CSS and was never intended to be worked with manually. It was just a single huge block of text, intimidating to say the least!

Spending most of a day to do so, I managed to split up the code a bit, sectioning parts off into new lines, but it is still hefty plus I'm not a CSS expert, so parts are still a bit messy and there are parts that I suspect (though not confident enough to remove them) are doing nothing like tags that don't seem to have attributes or multiple parts that are doing the same thing that is causing confusion and making any changes I do make far more complicated.

Essentially making just a few changes to the website has turned into a total slog, I've made some progress but it is really slow going. This is fine, but I don't want to end up hitting a brick wall where I just can't comprehend what is going on anymore.

Do you guys have any advice or tips as to how I can neaten up the CSS sheet and make it more readable? Perhaps you've had to deal with a similar issue and there are some techniques you picked up to make a poorly laid out sheet more manageable? I'm pretty open to any support you guys can bring, I know it's perhaps a bit of a weird issue, but this is me cutting my teeth in real world application of CSS and this seemed like the place to get some experienced help!

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide! If I have made a mess of this post, let me know and I'll edit it or if necessary remove it.

Comment: The CSS was probably minified from the nice readable format. Chrome has some help for that, as it can "un-minify" CSS as well as JavaScript files. There might even be some source-maps lying around for you to work with. Perhaps you can get in touch with the original programmer, and they still have the source code.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+beautifier

Comment: Hi @HoriaComan! Thank you for the advice :) Sadly the third party has since gone out of business I believe so can't follow them up for any help or more info sadly but I'll look into "un-minifying" the sheet!

Comment: I'll give that search a try @CBroe thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy option for this can be found right here on Stack Overflow: Example: If you have this block of CSS code (all in one line):

.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; }.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; }.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; }.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; }.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}.asd { margin: 12px; }.asd { margin: 12px; } .kjhsdf { padding:10px;}div.abc > .sdfg {width:500px;}

Now if you open a new snippet in an answer here (clicking the 7th icon from the left in the text editors top margin) and paste this code into the `CSS` section, you can the click `Tidy` in the left column of the snippet editor, the code is formatted as follows and can be copied/pasted anywhere you like:

```css
.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.asd {
  margin: 12px;
}

.kjhsdf {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.abc>.sdfg {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy help I'll check this out! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not overly apparent that Chrome has this nifty button built into the bottom bar to un-minify or pretty print a selected source in the inspector.

**Chrome inspector -> Sources tab -> { }**

[image]

Comment: That is going to come in really handy thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @Lee no problem :)